# A Data Structure Dictionary f.e for cars

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, dictionary

lets say that there is a dict given:

```
cars = {
  "brand": ["BMW", "Mercedes", "Audi", "Renault"],
  "model": ["M4", "a35", "rs7", "Megane"],
  "year": [2016, 2014, 2017, 2013],
}
```

How do i print it so the `expected output would be: BMW M4 2016, Mercedes a35 2014, Audi rs7 2017 etc..`
Of course you can change the dictionary if its wrong writtent, but i am just asking how to do like a data structure dictionary with cars.

Comment: You should create your `dict` the other way round, or just directly uses classes or `namedtuples` to represent your cars. Much cleaner. All the attributes are where they belong, attached to the object, not some unrelated data structure.

Comment: The more logical way of creating these dicts would be: `[{"brand": "BMW", "model": "M4", "year": 2016}, {"brand": ...}, ...]`. The way you currently did it doesn't require a dict. Just create three lists: `brands = [...] ; models = [...]`

Answer (score 4):

You can use simply a `zip` function then print it.

```
cars = {
  "brand": ["BMW", "Mercedes", "Audi", "Renault"],
  "model": ["M4", "a35", "rs7", "Megane"],
  "year": [2016, 2014, 2017, 2013],
}
for c,m,y in zip(cars['brand'],cars['model'],cars['year']):
    print(c,m,y)
```

Comment: Whilst you absolutely correct and answer the OP perfectly, I would still strongly discourage setting up dicts like this. They are simply not meant to be related on position between two or more lists as values. [EDIT] Try removing 2013 and notice the Renault disappears entirely.

Comment: Is there any other option how to do it without zip func. Task like that are on my classes and we can only use things that we learned already. I did not have zip function yet, but if there is not any other option then its fine. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Since the list element size is same so, I think it could be a better solution to get every value at the same using zip. Okay! it has a lot way to get value more preciously but then need to initialize additional class to set as object. Whereas, @randomobject123 you separated brand, model and year as different list. If your `JSON` value compact as brand, model and year dictionary then it could be easier to find another way

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `class Car` to represent a car, so all the attributes are actually part of the object they belong to, not stored in seemingly unrelated lists.

The next advantage is that you can expand the object with new attributes later on, and you can use methods to do work on it. And if done correctly, all the code outside of the class will still work after a change, because all the implementation details are handled in `class Car`.

For example you can "teach" a `Car` how to print itself, by implementing a `__str__` method, so your printing code does not need to know anything about the "inside" of your class to print it, and you can change the implementation of `__str__` later, without having to touch the code outside doing the printing.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, brand, model, year):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.brand}, {self.model}, {self.year}'

cars = [
    Car('BMW', 'M4', 2016),
    Car('Mercedes', 'a35', 2014),
    Car('Audi', 'rs7', 2017),
    Car('Renault', 'Megane', 2013)
]

for car in cars:
    print(car)
"""
BMW, M4, 2016
Mercedes, a35, 2014
Audi, rs7, 2017
Renault, Megane, 2013
"""

for car in cars:
    print(car.year)
"""
2016
2014
2017
2013
"""
```

You can easily convert your dictionary of lists into a list of `Car` instances [by using the other solution in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65124261/1170207):

```
cars = {
  "brand": ["BMW", "Mercedes", "Audi", "Renault"],
  "model": ["M4", "a35", "rs7", "Megane"],
  "year": [2016, 2014, 2017, 2013],
}
car_classes = [Car(*args) for args in zip(cars['brand'], cars['model'], cars['year'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can re-write the dictionary as a list of dictionaries.  As noted in the comments above, probably best to avoid using positional relations.

```
cars = [    
{"brand": "BMW", "model": "M4", "year": 2016}, 
{"brand": "Mercedes", "model": "a35", "year": 2014}, 
{"brand": "Audi", "model": "rs7", "year": 2017}, 
{"brand": "Renault", "model": "Megane", "year": 2013}, 
]

for car in cars:
    print(car["brand"], car["model"], car["year"])
```

OUTPUT:

```
BMW M4 2016
Mercedes a35 2014
Audi rs7 2017
Renault Megane 2013
```